# huge size of debug.log file in Magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, log, debug

I have created a cronjob which will create or update a number of products(around 2000 products, runs cron two times in a day). When the cron runs and update the products data, huge amount of "cache-invalidated" logs are written to debug.log file which largely increases the size of the debug.log. My system is in production mode. How can we block the system generated "cache-invalidated" logs.

Answer (score 0):

**It is an bug in magento 2.0 -2.1 version.**

You need to upgrade your system to 2.2 version than issue will be resolve.

***I have face same problem and for resolve this issue, i have run a cron job which is deleted that file 5 min interval***.